# JavaScript help/ issue with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm new into this but basically I'm trying to make a JavaScript loop, where 2 fighters fight. I made an array with the 2 fighters and a button connected to my JavaScript from HTML. Now I need to make a loop where the fighters hit each other where the damage by 1 fighter is subtracted by the health of the other so on, later I need to display how the fight went in my html. but I don't know where to start I would be thankful for some help. This is what I have done and I don't know what to do after or if it is even right?

```
var fighters =  [
{
  "name":"Abdi",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 20,
}
{
  "name": "chriz",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 11,
}

]
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fighters.length; i++) {
    fighters[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? If `fighters[0]` hits `fighters[1]`, it's just `fighters[1].HP -= fighters[0].DMG;`

Comment: yeah but viseversa as well so they hit each other

Comment: `fighters[0].HP -= fighters[1].DMG` for the other hit.

Comment: Use loops when the number of elements is dynamic or you need to do the same thing to every element of the array. But that's not the case here.

Comment: `function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fighters.length; i++) {
    fighters[1].HP -= fighters[0].DMG;
    fighters[0].HP -= fighters[1].DMG;
  }
`       something like this???

Comment: You don't need the loop! You're not doing anything with `fighters[i]`

Comment: `function myFunction() {
//  console.log("myFunction");

  while (fighters[0].HP > 0 && fighters[1].HP > 0) {
  fighters[1].HP -= fighters[0].DMG;
  fighters[0].HP -= fighters[1].DMG;
  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML+= fighters[1].HP;
  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML+= fighters[0].HP;
}

this solved it.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please write an answer in the Your Answer box. Please do not add the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {

  while (fighters[0].HP > 0 && fighters[1].HP > 0) {
  fighters[1].HP -= fighters[0].DMG;
  fighters[0].HP -= fighters[1].DMG;
  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML+= fighters[1].HP ;
  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML+= fighters[0].HP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing perfect.

Few things --

- `fighters[i]` refers to  a specific fighter. You may want to replace
  that line with some actual logic, for example `fighters[i].HP++`
  would increase their health by one.
- Your fighters array doesn't have a comma. You need one.
- You've defined the function that does what you need, but you haven't called it. You may want to call it by adding a line like `myFunction();`

Also, don't forget to output something or you'll never know what's happening! A lot of people use `console.log()` for that, e.g. `console.log(fighters[i].HP)`

(Note: I specifically did not add the logic you mentioned because I believe that's homework ;)

Comment: Where do you talk about one fighter inflicting damage on the other fighter based on their `DMG` property?

Comment: I personally refrain from directly answering homework questions as that would be detrimental to the student's development. Feel free to downvote if you disagree.

Comment: That's fine, but your answer doesn't even address anything in the question.

Comment: The part about the missing comma should just be a comment, it's clearly a copying error.

Comment: And the question says he has "a button connected to my javascript from html". That's how the function is called.